# How to avoid repeating "document.getElementById" calls in JS?

Tags: javascript, reduce, getelementbyid

Here is an exanple:

```
document.getElementById("field_a").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("field_b").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("field_c").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("field_d").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("field_a").style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.getElementById("field_b").style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.getElementById("field_c").style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.getElementById("field_d").style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Is it possible to make the same with less lines of code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're assigning the same colors to everything, why not iterate over a list of field names?

```
fields = ['field_a', 'field_b', ...]
fields.forEach(field => {
    const fieldEl = document.getElementById(field);
    fieldEl.style.color = "red";
    fieldEl.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});
```

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nodeList by document.querySelectorAll and Array.from()

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
let elements = Array.from(nodeList);

elements.map(x => x.style.color = 'red');
```

```html
<p class="field">Lorem</p>
<p class="field">Lorem</p>
<p class="field">Lorem</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question as worded:

```
const $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

Now these are equivalent, and you've saved `22` characters per call:

```js
$('field_a') == document.getElementById("field_a");
```

To make the example code you've shared more concise though, you can do this:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=field_]');
const elems = [...nodes];
elems.forEach(({ style }) => style.color = 'red' || (style.backgroundColor = 'white'));
```

```html
<span id=field_a>a</span>
<span id=field_b>b</span>
<span id=field_c>c</span>
<span id=field_d>d</span>
```

The selector `[id^=field_]` selects all elements whose `id` starts with `field_`.
Unfortunately, we are returned a `NodeList` instead of an `Array`, so it doesn't have a `.forEach` method (I would appreciate someone explaining why it was designed this way).

Fortunately, converting most iterables (like a `NodeList`) into an instance of `Array` is easy with the spread operator:

```js
[...nodeList]
```

Then we can use `.forEach` to loop through each of them.

In my example, I've used `({ style })` to get the `.style` property of each element, since it's the only object we want to mutate.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a class to all these elements and use `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll` to retrieve all of them and apply the rules with a loop.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
// or = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");

for (var element of elements) {
  element.style.color = "red";
  element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function. Read more about DRY and SRP

```
fields = ['a', 'b', ...]

fields.forEach(field => {
  changeColor(field, "red", "white");
})

function changeColor(id, color, bgColor)
{
  let field = document.getElementById(id);
  field.style.color = color;
  field.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var fields = document.querySelectorAll ("[data-js='field']");` will return all the elements that have an attribute `data-js` = "field"

then you can loop through these elements with `fields.forEach` and set the color and the background color of each one like the code below

The attribute `data-field-type` can be used to select a specific field. Ex: `var field_a = document.querySelector("[data-field-type='a']");`

(In the code only 3 fields were used)

```js
var fields = document.querySelectorAll ("[data-js='field']");

fields.forEach (function (_field){
  _field.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<div data-js="field" data-field-type="a">field a</div>
<div data-js="field" data-field-type="b">field b</div>
<div data-js="field" data-field-type="c">field c</div>
```